# The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version [release app with other informations]

Tags: android, release

I have the following problem:

My partner traveled to Germany and took the notebook with our app code with him. He sent me the code by email and I finished the app update. But we released the app in Google Play from the Note and now I need to release a new version but I don't have the keystore used in firsts releases.

When I export the ".apk" I am asked for a password, what password is that? And if I create a new debug.keystore and new Alias I have this error I mencioned above.

Can I do something to release the atualization? Do I have to know any information?

Sorry for one more post with the same title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For update of same application, apk should be exported with same signature and password which was used earlier, failing to do so, your apk will be considered as new application and not update of same application.

Comment: I will see around for this, but as per my knowledge, you have to keep password handy with you and unfortunately no way out to extract it

Comment: password as well as keystore should be remembered always

Comment: Yeah, I found how can I get the alias and the password storage in the keystore. Thank you. And vote up my question, please.

Comment: and accept answer, which ever you feel was good enough for your query.

Answer (score 3):

first, your app must be signed with the same key. there's no way around this. you can have you partner send you the `.keystore` file they used in the signing of the app presently uploaded to google play.

second, you need to have the keystore alias, keystore passphrase, and alias passphrase (password). these were entered when the `.keystore` file was created.

exercise caution when transmitting this information. if someone obtains your `.keystore` file, they can use it to sign their apps, thereby allowing their apps to communicate with your app in trusted ways.

Answer (score 0):

As Zoombie said, you must sign it with the same keystore and password, as well as take note not to change the package name; all of which would lead it to be thought of as a different application. There are 2 passwords that you will need to input, one for the keystore and one for its alias.